# MySQL union/join row with column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system where i have dynamic user information.  Basically i have a users table with an id, name, email, and password (the required basics).  And if the system admin wants to add a user field they can do so by adding a new entry into the user_fields table, where then the data for that field gets stored in user_fields_data.

user:

```
id | name      | email         | password
=============================================
1  | bob smith | bob@gmail.com | asdfasdfasdf
...
```

user_fields:

```
id | field
==========
1  | address_1
2  | address_2
...
```

user_fields_data:

```
user_id | field_id | value
===============================
1       | 1        | 123 abc st
1       | 2        | suite 314
```

Basically my goal is to perform a single query where i can get all of the information.

```
array(
    'name'      => 'bob',
    'email'     => 'bob@gmail.com',
    'password'  => 'asdfasdfasdf',
    'address_1' => '123 abc st',
    'address_2' => 'suite 314'
)
```

I join tables together all day long, however i've never had to join one in this manner (row / column).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the moment? nothing ^^.  I know how to perform this using two seperate SQL statements, but dont even know how to start with this type of a join.

Comment: this is a regular old join...  just write the sql.  the problem is you will get many rows back - and that will need to be unwound in the presentation layer.  boo for this poor schema design.

Comment: @Randy Correct, and I'm not looking to get all of the data in users back in every single row. How would you go about changing the schema?

Answer (score 3):

```
select 'name' as name, name as value from user where id = 1
union all
select 'email', email from user where id = 1
union all
select 'password', password from user where id = 1
union all
select uf.field, ufd.value
from user_fields_data ufd 
inner join user_fields uf on ufd.field_id = uf.id
where ufd.user_id = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f346f/11)

Output:

```
|      NAME |         VALUE |
-----------------------------
|      name |     bob smith |
|     email | bob@gmail.com |
|  password |  asdfasdfasdf |
| address_1 |    123 abc st |
| address_2 |     suite 314 |
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. However i guess i was looking for a more simpler answer as my user table has about 7 or 8 fields (which will make this type of query a bit daunting, lol).  Much thanks!

Comment: @MichaelLynch Well, this is much more easily done in the application layer, so choose your poison.

Comment: Yea, as this was exactly what i was looking for.  I just went ahead and did it in two separate queries where on the first i get all (*) fields in the users table, in case in the future i have to put more fields there.  Makes the one query work even if i have to go back later and add more.  I appreciate your response and thanks for showing me SQL-Fiddle (i've used others, just never knew there was one for SQL).

Answer (score 0):

If you know what custom fields you will be joining you can do something like this example [Compex MySQL Left Join using multiple entries from meta tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735176/compex-mysql-left-join-using-multiple-entries-from-meta-tables)